# (Lebesgue) Integral of this disgusting function

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
3&x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\\
2&x\in\mathbb{Q}^c\cap[0,1].
\end{cases}$$

I wish to find the numerical value of this integral. It should be 3 len($A$) + 2 len ($B$), where $A$ is the first set above and $B$ the second, so I think that $\mu(A) = 0$, as a countable set is a null set, and $\mu(B) = 1$, so that the value of the integral is just 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. To nitpick, I'd replace "len" with $\mu$.

Comment: Yes, I would too, but this problem comes before the section where we define measure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is correct because the Lebesgue-measure of a countable set is $0$.
\begin{align} 
\int\limits_{[0,1]} f \,d \mu &=  \int\limits_{[0,1]}\left(
2\cdot\operatorname{\chi}\limits_{[0,1] \setminus \mathbb Q} + 3\cdot\operatorname{\chi}\limits_{[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q} 
\right)d \mu \\
&= 2\mu([0,1] \setminus\mathbb Q) + 3\mu([0,1] \cap \mathbb Q) \\
&= 2(\mu([0,1]) - 0) + 0 \\
&= 2 
\end{align}